# Check Eloquent wasChanged on hasMany/belongsTo Model relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-9

I want to check the `wasChanged()` status of my child/detail models, just as I do with the parent/header model in the `hasMany`(parent) :: `belongsTo` (child) relationship.

I've got code that looks like this:

```php
$parent = Parent::updateOrCreate([ ... ], [ ... ]);
if ($parent->wasChanged()) {
    // do something useful
}
foreach ($contents as $child) {
    $parent->children()->updateOrCreate([ keys ],[ data ]);
    // Now I want to check if the Child model named Contents was changed.
    // if ($parents->children()->wasChanged()) { ...  // does not work
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You mean you are looking through $parent->children as $child ? What is $contents here ?

Comment: `$contents` is just the collection of new data that is being added as one new child item per element of the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not even sure this is a correct answer, but what I ended up doing and seems to be working is adding `save()` calls after each `createOrUpdate()` call.  The Laravel documentation suggests this is *not* how it is supposed to work, but it's hard to argue with empirical evidence.

```php
$parent = Parent::updateOrCreate([ keys ],[ data ]);

if ($header->wasChanged() || $header->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    // Do interesting work
}
$parent->save();

foreach ($myInterestingData as $newChildData) {
    $child = $header->children()
        ->updateOrCreate( ... keys/values from $newChildData ...);
    if ($child->wasChanged() || $child->wasRecentlyCreated) {
        // Do boring work
    }

    $child->save();
}
```

Comment: Righ, you can also use **$model->touch();** to update the timestamps, perhaps you can check for changes that way: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `$contents` does, but, you could always do something like this to accomplish the idea of what you want done:

```
$parent = Parent::updateOrCreate([ keys ],[ data ]);

$parent->load('children');
        
if ($parent->wasChanged()) {
    // do something useful
}

$parent->children()->updateOrCreate([ keys ],[ data ]);  
  
foreach($parent->children() as $child) {
    if ($child->wasChanged()) {
        // do something useful
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost works.  It only reports changes, however.  If the model is created, it appears `wasChanged()` is false.  I think maybe I can use `$model->wasRecentlyCreated` but have not gotten to testing it thoroughly yet.